# How to do user added images on android studio?

Tags: java, android

How would I be able to get access to the user's photos and let them pick out an image/video (e.g. picture for a thumbnail)? Where would it be stored?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link to provide a user to pick images from their gallery :

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

As for where it would be stored, the answer is it really does depend on the implementation you have. You can either save that image locally or you could push to file to an external server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to add an image to the internal storage

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap, name: String) {
        val saved: Boolean
        val fos: OutputStream?
        fos = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val resolver: ContentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
            val contentValues = ContentValues()
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/$IMAGE_DIRECTORY")
            val imageUri =
                resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri!!)
        } else {
            val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
            ).toString() + File.separator + IMAGE_DIRECTORY
            val file = File(imagesDir)
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir()
            }
            val image = File(imagesDir, "$name.png")
            FileOutputStream(image)
        }
        saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
        fos!!.flush()
        fos.close()
    }
```